# Fetching firebase data from a service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the user value from the **firebase.service.ts** in my component file.

What is the way to return the user so that they are accessible in my **stats.component.ts** file? How to return the value inside a then block in service so that myData variable in component.ts has the updated user value from the service.

#### firebase.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable as RxObservable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import * as firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";


@Injectable()
export class DataService {


    user= [];


    constructor() { }

    firebaseInit() {

        firebase.init({
        }).then(
            () => {
               // console.log("initialized");
                 firebase.getValue('/companies')
                    .then(result => {
                        // JSON.stringify(result) will return the json object
                        // result.value will get the value 

                        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.value));
                        this.user = result.value;   


                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log("Error:" + error));        
        }
        ).catch(
            (err) => {console.log("Error is: " + err)}
        )


    }


     sendData() {
        console.log( "Outside firebaseInit" + this.user);

     }


}
```

#### stats.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from "../services/firebase.service";

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    templateUrl: "./stats.component.html"
})


export class StatsComponent {

    private mydata;

    constructor(private dataService:DataService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){

       this.mydata =  this.dataService.firebaseInit();;

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method in your service. You should return data in your method

#### service

```
firebaseInit() {

    return firebase.init({
    }).then(
        () => {
           // console.log("initialized");
            return  firebase.getValue('/companies')
                .then(result => {
                    // JSON.stringify(result) will return the json object
                    // result.value will get the value 

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.value));
                    this.user = result.value;   
                    return this.user;

                })
                .catch(error => console.log("Error:" + error));        
    }
    ).catch(
        (err) => {console.log("Error is: " + err)}
    )
}
```

#### In your component

```
ngOnInit(){

       this.dataService.firebaseInit().then(data => this.mydata = data);

    }
```

Comment: WHen you use arrow functions you need to ue the key word return to return data

Answer (score 0):

You have to return every function and result inside .then function, any missing return will break the promise chain.

You can directly return result without assigning to another variable.

```
firebaseInit() {

    return firebase.init({
    }).then(
        () => {
           // console.log("initialized");
             return firebase.getValue('/companies')
                .then(result => {
                    // JSON.stringify(result) will return the json object
                    // result.value will get the value 

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.value));
                    return result.value;   


                })
                .catch(error => console.log("Error:" + error));        
    }
    ).catch(
        (err) => {console.log("Error is: " + err)}
    )


}
```